# Centering pie charts with Plotly

Tags: r, r-plotly

I already plot this two pie charts on the same plot with plotly. Below you can see code and my data:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(invisible(
                             lapply(c("plotly", "dplyr"), require, character.only = TRUE)))
                           
                           Share <- structure(list(Y = c(2018, 2018, 2019, 2019), 
                                                   Categorie = c("Before","After", "Before","After"), 
                                                   Share = c(1.0,99., 3, 97)), 
                                              row.names = c(NA,-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 
                           
p <- plot_ly() %>%
                             add_pie(data=Share, labels = ~Categorie , values = ~Share, hole = 0.6,
                                     name = "fig1", domain = list(x = c(0, 0.4), y = c(0.4, 1))) %>%
                             add_pie(data=Share, labels = ~Categorie , values = ~Share, hole = 0.6,
                                     name = "fig2", domain = list(x = c(0.6, 1), y = c(0.4, 1)))  %>%
                             layout(title = "Donut sub-plots", showlegend = FALSE,
                                    font=list(family="sans serif", color="#000"),
                                    plot_bgcolor="#f0f0f0",
                                    legend = list(orientation = 'h',font=list(size=28)),
                                    xaxis = list(title="", showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                                    yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
                           p
```

[image]

You can see from plot that both pie chart are in in the upper part of the image.But I want to have two equal pie charts with position of center of the image. So can anybody help me how to do that in plotly ?

Comment: Why do you need them at the center? Where are you using it?

Comment: First I will use like pdf output and after that like embedded chart in Rmarkdown document pdf.

Comment: Adjust your domain such that the pies are centered, e.g. `y = c(0.1, .9)` and setting `hole = 0.5`

Comment: This really works. Thank you !